# Artifacts on mirror modifier with Subdivision. Normals are correct

Tags: subdivision-surface, artifacts, mirror-modifier

So I have these strange Artifacts on this Object.

[image]

I tried changing the order of Mirror and Subdiv. modifier but that doesnt help. Normals are correct and no duplicate of vertices.

If I change the Subdivision lebels to 2 it looks stranger.

[image]

And when I apply scale in object mode it looks even stranger.

[image]

Comment: Can you upload your .blend file to https://blend-exchange.com/ ?

Comment: Just found the solution

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I found the answer.

1. I deleted the face of the Object on the Mirror Plane
2. I Accidently copied the Object and had the same Object overlap itself without noticing.